# orientation specific values do not change

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I got dimension values set in both values and values-land folders and used as the width/height of a layout.
I change the screen-orientation programmatically to landscape in my activity:

```
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

but the layout dimensions are not the ones declared in values-land folder dimens.xml.

I suspect that since the orientation is specific just to this activity, the application doesn't provide the updated resources.

Is there a way to change the orientation of the whole application, or reference to the landscape resources from code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I realized that this behavior is normal. I solved my problem by loading a different layout with different dimensions.